# Best procedure for updating my exe running as a windows service

Tags: windows, inno-setup, updating

I have been doing a good amount of research on an update procedure for my exe running as a windows service. I am basically using Inno Setup and my exe. I am looking for the best way to update my exe. Here is my current procedure:

> Innosetup.exe contains two exe's. Mainapp.exe and Updater.exe

```
1.) Innosetup.exe is executed on the endpoint, creates directories, registry keys, etc.
2.) It registers Mainapp.exe as a service and starts it. (Note that Updater.exe is not registered as a service or started)
3.) Mainapp.exe starts its main loop and checks the server for an update. If theres a update it launches the Updater.exe
4.) Updater.exe contacts the webserver and downloads the new_Innosetup.exe file and saves it to disk 
5.) Updater.exe executes new_Innosetup.exe
6.) new_Innosetup.exe stops Mainapp.exe, renames the exe to Mainapp.exe_old and then installs the updated Mainapp.exe. Also updates all the registry keys.
7.) Updater.exe checks if everything is healthy and then exits
```

I have coded about half of this process so far (up to step 4) and it seems to be working good but I think a lot of potential errors will be introduced after step 4.

Do this update procedure make sense and what could I change/improve to ensure that an update does not break the app?

Thank you

Comment: This quite broad question for Stack Overflow. -- Anyway, it should work. Though I do not understand, what the Updater.exe is good for. Why do you have two applications?

Comment: I guess I have the updated.exe program to ensure that the new Main exe downloaded is running and to roll back changes if anything breaks. I suppose I could replace it with the [Code] section of InnoSetup. But I’m not sure if this is recommended or not?

Comment: I feel like replicating this logic in Pascal (which I’m not great at) will be very tough.. no?

Comment: It seems to me that your Updater does what Inno Setup is intended to do. So it should be easy to implement it in Inno. But even if it is easier to you to code this in your preferred programming language, you do you really need to install the Updater. You can just extract it from the installer to a temporary location, run it to do, what is needed, and delete it.

Comment: True, I like the temp location idea and deleting it. I’ve seen other people install 2 services so that the “updater” could be updated. But I think the temp solution solves that. Thank you!